# What happened to my world‽

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This has happened to me twice now.  I create a world (survival, **not** hardcore), I play for a week or so, then, one day, when I go to open it, it's gone.

I've went to `.minecraft` and verified that the worlds are still there and they don't appear to be missing any files.

What's going on and how can I stop this from happening again?

And especially, can I get my worlds back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're closing minecraft in mid-stream while it's writing files then the level.dat file can be corrupted and result in your "world" disappearing. You can repair the world in [mcedit](http://davidvierra.com/mcedit.html) to get your world back. =)

*edit*

For further instructions this video seems to cover things adequately:

Comment: Practically every time I exit it it gives me a black screen that doesn't go away for several minutes, so this sounds plausible.  I will try MCEdit.  Would waiting at the main screen before exiting reduce my chances of it happening again?

Comment: I've never heard of this problem before, so maybe it would? I suspect it's a mod that is causing your java to crash on leaving your world, or something along similar lines. A java update might help too.

Comment: I have pure vanilla. It's running on Ubuntu though, in my experience I get this error on Ubuntu yet not on Windows XP. I will see about updating Java though.

Comment: AH, yeah I've heard bad things before (I can't remember specifics off the top of my head) regarding non win/mac operating systems and minecraft. I hate to wave my hand and say "oh that's just a mysterious mojang bug, sucks to be on ubuntu" but that's pretty much just a mysterious mojang bug for ubuntu/*nix operating systems. =/ A google search for general "black screen ubuntu" terms on the official minecraft forums returns nearly 900 results. If windows is an option for you then I highly recommend sticking with that.

Comment: If you're running Ubuntu, consider making a script that takes a copy of the world before launching the server/game, so that in the event Notch's code implodes you at least have a backup you can revert to.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the MCEdit repair process?

Comment: Apparently my world is beyond repair.  I opened it in MCEdit and chunks were missing.  Moving the spawn got the game to see it again, but when I loaded it it had regenerated most of the chunks from a different seed.  Oh well.  :(